# QEMU-KVM with VLANS and no bridges

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, virtualization, qemu

Please be gentle, I'm both a novice Ubuntu user and novice networking guy.

I'm trying to put together a virtual server to support a couple of telephony applications at my office.  Both applications run on different windows 2008 servers.  I've built a Ubuntu system using the desktop version of 15.04 and successfully added the virtual machines using the virtual network NAT option. I've also gotten the network within Ubuntu to work within the office which took a little bit of effort as our IT guy has VLANs implemented.  The network is 10.x.x.x (VLAN 20) with the virtual network of 192.168.1.x

So now here we come to my question.  How can I have my virtual machines be given direct access to the NIC so each VM can have an IP address on the 10.x.x.x network so my workstations and smartphones can have access to them?  I have 2 VMs and 2 NIC and would be fine with dedicating one NIC to each machine and only having physical access to the Ubuntu host.  To add another wrinkle, the IT guy has the managed switches programmed to disable the port if another switch, DHCP server or bridge is connected so I can't use bridging as described by various forums.

I appreciate the assistance that anyone can provide, and thank you in advance!

Comment: If the managed switch disables the port if it detects that there are more than two devices connected behind it, then there's not much you can do. You'll have to stick with NAT'ing. Correction: That was under the assumption you had only one NIC. With 2 NICs, there might be a way.

Comment: macvtap might be helpful here. I believe it allows the VM to communicate directly with the physical NIC card. I would add more details, but I don't know macvtap very well.